# Linq sum value in list iside other list

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

Goodevening I try to make a LINQ query on List of employers called people containing another List of jobs. I want to sum the int value of jobs. I try this code

```
public class Employe
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public List<Job> Jobs{ get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public int int1 { get; set; }
  public int int2 { get; set; }
}

var dati = from p in people
               from j in p.Jobs
               group j by j.id into g
               select new
               {
                 idp = p.id,
                 name = p.name,
                 value1 = g.sum(m => m.int1),
                 value2 = g.sum(m => m.int1)
               };
```

it doesn't work it give me the error "p doesn't exist"

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping by `j.id`, so after that grouping is done, `p` doesn't exist anymore.

Without knowing what you actually want to group by, it's hard to tell how to do what you're trying to do.

Also, your error is `The name 'p' does not exist in the current context`, and it's a compiler error, not a runtime exception. When you put errors into your question, please make sure it's exact and detailed.

Comment: @ Joe Enos Thank you very much for the answer. Sorry for the imprecision of the error. I want to group jobs of single employer and sum the vaue (int1 and int2) but i want to retrieve the people data to. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Create your group on **p** and **g** Only then you can access values of both object.

```
var dati = from p in people 
                           from j in p.Jobs
                           group new {j,p} by j.id into g
                           select new
                           {
                               idp = g.FirstOrDefault().p.id,
                               name = g.FirstOrDefault().p.name,
                               value1 = g.Sum(m => m.j.int1),
                               value2 = g.Sum(m => m.j.int1)
                           };
```

Comment: @ Muhammad Nasir Thank You for the answer I'll try as far as possible your suggest

Comment: i personally think you should us join that will make your query more readable and easy to implement